# How to add Type to an object of n element Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to assign types to objects which have different keys and values but "other" is the same to all of them. how can I type them with typescript

```
{
  color: "red",
  size: "small",
  other: {
     price: 345
     discount: 10
  }
}

{
  ram: "4 GB",
  brand: "Samsung",
  other: {
     price: 755
     discount: 30
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a limited set of type of objects or the fields other than `other` can be a random number and contain every possible key?

Comment: [prop:string]: string

Comment: n number of fields

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the more generic case.

```
class Item {
    other: {
       price: number;
       discount: number;
    };
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

However, if you could find some boundaries and for example identify some specific cases would be way better to have a `super-class` with `other` and then declare `sub-classes` for the custom (but still defined and limited) fields, like:

```
class Item {
    other: {
       price: number;
       discount: number;
    };
}

class Wearable extends Item {
     size: string;
     color: string;
}

class Ram extends Item {
     capacity: string;
     brand: string;
}
```

Comment: the order of fields are important ?

Comment: No, it's not :)

Comment: so [key: string]: string means n element ?

Comment: means you can add to your object as many values as you want, that are strings, in the form of `something: "aaa", somethingElse: "aaa"`. If you also don't care about the type (then why using custom classes in first place?) just go with `[key: string]: any` and you can put it there whatever you want :)