# How to assign types for the elements in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface initialStateInterface {
  user: object;
  age: number;
}

const initialState = {
  user: { username: "", email: "" },
  age: 0,
};
```

Here I have the interface type assigned to the user which is an **object**. Is there any way to assign the types to it's elements?

What I'm trying to do,

```
user: (username: string,email: string).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Type to an object of n element Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62369116/how-to-add-type-to-an-object-of-n-element-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interfate userType {
    username: string,
    email: string
}

interface initialStateInterface {
  user: userType;
  age: number;
}
```